# sql oracle procedures with select

Tags: oracle, select, procedure

I have some problems with procedures when it comes to using select

I need a procedure that shows me the years of experience of a certain employee

It looks like this: I write a name of that employee and it shows me the years

And I come up with something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_emp (fname in varchar2(20))
AS
emp_fname employee.fname%TYPE;
emp_hire_date employee.hire_date%TYPE;
BEGIN
select fname, hire_date in emp_fname, emp_hire_date FROM employee
where emp_fname = fname 
and emp_hire_date = months_between(sysdate, hire_date)/12;
if emp_hire_date > 30
then 
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (emp_fname ||'worked'||emp_hire_date||'years')
end if;
end;
```

It returns me the PLS-00103 error
And also I do not really think I need this two strings

```
emp_fname employee.fname%TYPE;
emp_hire_date employee.hire_date%TYPE;
```

And I tried to use

```
DECLARE emp_years in NUMBER;
```

But it does not works either

Comment: you mean `into` not `in`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several things wrong in the procedure

- in DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE you have to add `;` (terminator) or you ll have an error.
- in the select you have to add `into` instead of `in`.
- in the procedure you dont have to specify the length of varchar2.
- in the condition , why you adding the date condition? you want the total year year of employee
- what do you need from the name in the select you already have it.
- in the `if` condition, what do you mean by 30 ? I specified if the employee more then a year then we will have a dbms output

This is the final procedure

```
-- adding data
 insert into employee (FIRST_NAME,last_name,hire_date) values('Mike','WHITE' ,to_date('01/08/2015','DD/MM/YYYY'));
commit;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_emp (fname varchar2)
AS
emp_fname VARCHAR2(100);
emp_hire_date number;
BEGIN

select ROUND(months_between(sysdate, hire_date)/12) into  emp_hire_date FROM employee
where FIRST_NAME = 'MIKE';
--and hire_date = sysdate - floor(months_between(sysdate, hire_date)/12);

if  emp_hire_date > 0
then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (emp_fname ||' worked'||emp_hire_date||' years.');
end if;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But I cant execute this one, it returns a couple of errors.
ORA-06550
PL-00306

Comment: @MarkoPolo  give me few minute and ill give you a complete example with data and explanation.

Comment: Thank you very much @Moudiz, and I also edited your code too.

Comment: @MarkoPolo your welcome , i forget to mention that `ROUND` function will give you value depends on the decimal for example if he was working 20 month which means 1.8 years .. the ROUND will give you 2 years .. if you want only 1 year decpite the value of decimal you can use `FLOOR` function

Answer (score 0):

Much thanks to @Moudiz with this issue, but I edited his code too
Now it looks like exactly what I needed

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_emp (fnamee varchar2)
AS
emp_fname VARCHAR2(100);
emp_hire_date number;
BEGIN
select fname, ROUND(months_between(sysdate, hire_date)/12) into  emp_fname,         
emp_hire_date FROM employee
where fname = fnamee;
if  emp_hire_date > 0
then
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (emp_fname ||' worked '||emp_hire_date||' years.');
end if;
end;
```

So you just write a name of the employee and the procedure returns the amount of years he had been working

```
begin
check_emp ('Philip');
end;
```